# Django: djcelery Import error from celery import current_app as celery in virtualenv

Tags: django, celery, virtualenv, django-celery, djcelery

Okay so I have tried everything I and google can come up. I'm trying to run django-celery under a virtualenv on my Macbook Pro OSX 10.8.4. I installed django-celery using pip while the virtualenv was activated. I get the following when importing djcelery in virtualenv python.

```
(platform)Chriss-MacBook-Pro:platform Chris$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import djcelery
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Chris/Development/platform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from celery import current_app as celery  # noqa
ImportError: cannot import name current_app
```

I have tried to start a completely clean virtualenv but still seem to get the same error. I have tried upgrading the modules and have.

Here is also a list of my pip freeze packages.

```
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
Django==1.5
MySQL-python==1.2.4c1
PIL==1.1.7
Pillow==2.0.0
amqp==1.0.12
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==2.7.3.30
boto==2.9.6
celery==3.0.20
certifi==0.0.8
chardet==2.1.1
django-activelink==0.3
django-activity-stream==0.4.4
django-appconf==0.6
django-celery==3.0.17
django-compressor==1.2
django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4
django-flag==0.1.1
django-guardian==1.1.1
django-ses==0.4.1
django-tinymce==1.5.1
django-userena==1.2.0
easy-thumbnails==1.2
html5lib==1.0b1
jsonfield==0.9.13
kombu==2.5.12
oauthlib==0.1.3
pisa==3.0.33
pyPdf==1.13
pyasn1==0.1.7
python-dateutil==2.1
python-memcached==1.53
pytz==2013b
reportlab==2.7
requests==0.13.1
requests-oauth==0.4.1
rsa==3.1.1
six==1.3.0
vimeo-wrapper==0.0.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you sure that current_app is defined in celery module?

Comment: Uhm it's how I got it out of the box. Where should I define it? I didn't see anything in the celery first steps - http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#configuring-your-django-project-to-use-celery about defining it so I would take it that it should just work.

Comment: Okay so I manage to figure out that the import djcelery works if I'm outside my project folder but still won't work when inside the folder. I'm not sure how this could cause a problem as there is nothing which changes the enviroment in the project folder.

Comment: Actually there is a difference - you may need to alter sys.path if you are under virtualenv. Can you post your django startup script - default is manage.py ?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I manage to find the issue. In my project folder I had the main project subfolder named platform. Seems this must have clashed with something as when I renamed it the import started working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Now everything is clear, I've edited your answer accordingly - please accept. Please note fellow Python programmers - `It is unwise to name your modules like existing ones from stdlib or pypi.` Module finding is documented in Python, but one can get confused if he/she didn't ensured module name uniqueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems there was a clash between something in djcelery and my project folders.

The folder structure I was using was something like this

```
\-project
--manage.py
--requirements.txt
\---platform
----app1
----app2
----etc
```

It seems the platform folder was colliding with something in the import as soon as I changed this the import started functioning correctly.

Thanks for all the help and comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a folder in your project called 'celery' rename it to something else. :)

Answer (score -1):

Did you wrote into the `settings.py`?:

> ```
> INSTALLED_APPS = (
>     ...
>     'djcelery',
>     ...
> )
> ```

If you want work with Django's enviroment you must run console as

`./manage.py shell`

or

`./manage.py shell --settings=path_to_settings_file_without_extention`