# Django-Celery Import Error: Cannot Import name current_app

Tags: python, django, celery, pyinstaller

I'm packaging a Django app with PyInstaller. I get the following output when I attempt to run the final exe.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
    File "c:\users\alex\.virtualenvs\pychampion\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-   2.1.1dev_-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
    File "Z:\01. Python Development\pychamp\build\project\out00-PYZ.pyz\pychamp", line 4, in <module>
    File "c:\users\alex\.virtualenvs\pychampion\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1.1dev_-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
    File "Z:\01. Python Development\pychamp\build\project\out00-PYZ.pyz\pychamp.settings", line 13, in <module>
    File "c:\users\alex\.virtualenvs\pychampion\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1.1dev_-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
    File "Z:\01. Python Development\pychamp\build\project\out00-PYZ.pyz\djcelery", line 22, in <module>
    ImportError: cannot import name current_app
```

The weird thing is that I only get this importerror after I've run pyInstaller. The app runs great before freezing. [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371307/django-djcelery-import-error-from-celery-import-current-app-as-celery-in-virtua) seemed very similar to what I'm facing as I'm also running from a virtualenv, but renaming the project directory didn't do anything. My current structure is

```
    pychamp
    \--pychamp
       \--settings.py
    \--pyapp
    \--manage.py
```

My guess is that it's another issue with PyInstaller not catching an import but I can't figure out what import I'm missing. Referencing the [Pyinstaller Recipe](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/Recipe/DjangoApplication), I've been putting some imports into the manage.py without any luck. I've read through as many different Google searches as I could to figure this out, but I've run out of ideas. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from pychamp import settings
    import djcelery
    from django.template.loaders.filesystem import Loader
    from django.template.loaders.app_directories import Loader
    import django.template.defaulttags
    import django.template.defaultfilters
    import django.template.loader_tags
    import django.test
    import HTMLParser
    import django.contrib.sessions.serializers
```

**UPDATE**

I never did figure out what was going on with Celery. I ended up reworking the code to not use Celery and this is my manage.py so pyinstaller would import all the needed libraries.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "pychamp.settings")

    from django.conf import settings
    import Cookie
    import django.test
    import HTMLParser
    import django.contrib.sessions.serializers
    import django.contrib
    import django.core.mail.backends.smtp
    import django.core.management.commands.sql
    import django.core.management.commands.sqlall
    import django.core.management.commands.sqlclear
    import django.core.management.commands.sqlinitialdata
    import django.core.management.commands.sqlsequencereset
    import django.template.loader
    import django.views.defaults
    import django.templatetags
    import googlecharts
    from googlecharts import templatetags
    from googlecharts.templatetags import googlecharts
    import django.core.serializers
    from django.core.serializers import json
    from django.templatetags import future

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```